# How should i compare this MAE results

Tags: time-series, mae

I'm in need of help to correctly interpret these results.

I am analyzing a time series of crime data. The series has 351,980 events.

These are the results of the predictions using a regression model:
[image]

I cannot compare the result of the model using 6 clusters and 84 clusters, since the series has 5,414 days per cluster, if I use only 6 clusters we will have 10.83 crimes per day on average, if we use 84 clusters I will have 0.77 events per day.

If with 6 clusters the average is 10.83 events per day, then a MAE of 1.97 gives an average error of almost 18%, already using 84 clusters with an average of 0.77 events per day, a MAE of 0.63 means an average error of 81%, I understand that this is incorrect.

How should i compare this?